# Limit involving the totient function and combination

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, limits, binomial-coefficients, totient-function

Do you think the following limits are correct?

$\displaystyle\lim_{d\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{d} {\varphi(N) \choose  k} {d-1 \choose k-1}}{\varphi(N)^d}=0$

$\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{d} {\varphi(N) \choose  k} {d-1 \choose k-1}}{\varphi(N)^d}=c$

I plotted the equations and guessed the results according to the graphs but I could not prove them mathematically by myself. Any hints would be appreciated. Graphs are as follows:

http://deniz.cs.utsa.edu/plots/

Thanks,

Comment: What is $N$ in the first one? What is $d$ in the second one?

Comment: I changed \phi to \varphi, if you don't like it you can hit revert but I think that is an improvement.

Comment: $N$ in the first one and $d$ in the second one are positive integers.

Comment: Posted also in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42181/limit-involving-the-totient-function-and-combination

Answer (score 1):

From [MathOverflow user JBL](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42181/limit-involving-the-totient-function-and-combination/42194#42194):

We have the [Vandermonde identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^d {\varphi(N) \choose k} {d-1 \choose k-1} = {d + \varphi(N) - 1 \choose d}.
$$

Thus with $N$ fixed, the numerator of your fraction is polynomial in $d$ and the result follows (with the exception of the values $N = 1, 2$).

The second result follows by the same analysis, since $\varphi(N) \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$.  In particular, the resulting constant is $\frac{1}{d!}$.